# Django Model Won't Validate or Not Installed

Tags: django, django-models

Can you see why I am getting this model validation error?

- I have the table in MySQL called '**paypal_transactions**' with records.
- I'm trying to copy this project over to another computer with the existing database.

**Error Message:**

```
One or more models did not validate: store.purchase: 'paypal_transaction' has a
relation with model <class 'f3.paypal.models.PaypalPaymentTransactions'>, which 
has either not been installed or is abstract.
```

**paypal/models.py**

```
class PaypalPaymentTransactions(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'paypal_transactions'

    payment_id = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    payer = models.CharField(max_length = 25)
    amount = models.DecimalField(decimal_places = 2, max_digits = 8,
                                 blank = True, default = "0.00")
    currency = models.CharField(max_length = 10)
```

**store/models.py**

```
from f3.paypal.models import PaypalPaymentTransactions

class Purchase(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name = 'purchase_user')
    product = models.ForeignKey(Design)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    paypal_transaction = models.ForeignKey(
        PaypalPaymentTransactions,
        default = None,
        null = True,
        blank = True)
```

Comment: Did you run `syncdb`?

Comment: Yeah -- it gives me the same error, I can't move on from that point.

Comment: is `paypal` in `INSTALLED_APPS` ?

Comment: either what @karthikr said or you have circular dependency issue for witch you need to pass the model name as string.

Comment: Yeah paypal is in settings.PY installed apps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error occurs probably because of a dependency issue:

Try use the ForeignKey like this:

```
class Purchase(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name = 'purchase_user')
    product = models.ForeignKey(Design)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    paypal_transaction = models.ForeignKey(
        'f3.paypal.PaypalPaymentTransactions',
        default = None,
        null = True,
        blank = True)
```

Comment: Thats a good answer and it correct! I had PIP installed Paypal, yet we have a Paypal class that doesn't use a Paypal library because it was messy. So I uninstalled Paypal through Pip.